# Calculate the derivative, by definition, the following function of several variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\begin{align}
f&:&\Bbb{R}&\to\Bbb{R}^2\\
&&p&\mapsto(\cos p,\sin p)
\end{align}$$

The definition my professor uses is:
$$(Df)(p)(v)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(p+tv)-f(p)}{t} $$

What i've done:
I applied in the formula the transformation, and so i get:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{[\cos(p+tv),\sin(p+tv)]-[\cos{p},\sin{p}]}{t}$$
and  working on it, using the $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ and so on...:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\cos(p)[\cos(tv)-1]-\sin(p)\sin(tv),\sin(p)[\cos(tv)-1]+\cos(p)\sin(tv))}{t}$$
And i'm not getting out this part. I wonder what concept i forgot to break here? I know i need to get $(-\sin(p),\cos(p))$ but how?

Comment: What does it mean $\cos(tv)?$ You have to write $v=(v_1,v_2).$

Comment: @mfl my friend, that's what she write in class and we have to figure it out alone what kind of terminology she's using. But indeed, $v$ is a vector. But i not so sure it's a $(v_1,v_2)$ because i thought the vector $v$ was from the domain.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandig the question. Actually $v\in\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation actually does lead to the correct solution. You just need to convince yourself that $\displaystyle\mathrm{lim}_{t\to 0} \frac{\mathrm{cos}(vt)-1}{t}=0$ and $\displaystyle\mathrm{lim}_{t\to 0} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(vt)}{t}=v$. One possible tool to see this would be L'Hôpital's rule.

Edit: I should add that what you wrote you are expecting to get is actually the derivative as a linear map at the point $p$. That means that you will get an additional factor $v$ when you apply this to a vector $v$ in order to form the directional derivative, as you did in your calculation.